# What is `C-/` do in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I recently mapped my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to make using emacs easier.  Most of the time it is awesome but one unintended consequence is that `C-/` is a frequent typo when I am going for the `?` (i.e., <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>).  When this happens I lose text and I can't undo it with `C-z` but I am not sure exactly what is happening.

What is `C-/` doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> runs the command undo. (unless it's been remapped)

You can always find out what a command does by asking emacs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> runs the describe-key function.
You type the above , enter a key sequence, and Emacs tells you what it does.